# what factor (in dB) is the output SNR or signal power affected by this phase error?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, digital-communications, bpsk

In a BPSK system, if at the receiver the oscillator has a phase error of phi =40° i.e. you are
multiplying the received signal with an appropriate cosine signal phase shifted by 40°. Then,
after low pass filtering, by what factor (in dB) is the output SNR or signal power affected by
this phase error?

Comment: Looks like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: @YouKnowWho you do realize that passing off others' work as your own on homework and exams is cheating, right?

Comment: @nanofarad ok but what to do when everyone is compared relative and everyone else is doing same thing will my cgpa will be placed above them just because i was honest. When everyone does the same thing and in last only end result will be remembered then what one should do ?

Comment: @YouKnowWho You could just learn the content and answer the question yourself. If you developed the correct mathematics and comm theory background, it is reasonable for you to derive the answer yourself, and as an added benefit, you'll actually be able to do this kind of analysis in the real world. If you're cheating instead of learning the material yourself, then you're not learning and are just wasting your education. Likewise, the assertion that cheating -> higher GPA is total bollocks in my experience.

Comment: @nanofarad okay i agree , i should have learned But my field is Information Technology this is the last  of electrical in my under graduation (and due to lockdown thing are being messed up.)and it was last assignment (time limited). And i like your caring attitude toward other keep it up.

Comment: @YouKnowWho Yeah, the lockdown is hard on everyone, but even then you'll gain more from working through the problems yourself. You might be working in IT, but one day come across a piece of communication equipment that reports bit error rates, and your experience from this class will help you understand what is going on and how to act on it. Best of luck with your classes.

Answer (score 1):

at 45 degree error, the Inphase and the Quadrature mixer results will be equal in amplitude.

At 45, the amplitude of INphase will be weaker by 0.707 factor.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it based on the EVM degradation. Assuming 2N symbols were sent, then the RMS-EVM will be:

$$EVM_{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{N((1-cos\phi)^2 + sin^2\phi) + N((-1+cos\phi)^2 + sin^2\phi)}{2N}}$$
$$EVM_{rms} = 2sin\frac{\phi}{2} = 2sin20^\circ = 0.68$$
$$EVM_{rms}(dB) = 20log_{10}(0.68) = -3.35dB$$
SNR degradation is just the negative of the RMS EVM in dB, thus:
$$SNR = - EVM_{rms}(dB) = 3.35dB$$